# R code to split data in a single column (of variable length per record) into columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

### I have data in a single Excel column thus:

```
123456
$200 
Bidder A
$300 
Bidder B
$320 
Bidder C
~
987654
$12 
Bidder X
$15 
Bidder Y
$20 
~
…
```

---

The first record contains 3 bids, the second record only 2 bids. Can be up to 40 bids per record or just 1 bid per record, so the number of rows per record varies. The "~" is "new record" delimiter.

### I want to convert this (ideally within R) to this format:

```
123456  Bidder A    $200    Bidder B    $300    Bidder C    $320    … <up to 40 bids & amounts>
987654  Bidder X    $12     Bidder X    $15     Bidder Y    NULL    … <up to 40 bids & amounts> 
...
...
```

### etc

I can read it into R from CSV easy enough, but would really appreciate help in working out how to change the form in an elegant way. My instincts are suggesting doing it the long way (write a bit of code to just keep reading down the column row by row and putting into columns until my "~" delimiter is reached, then starting a new line) but I'm trying to resist and learn R too :-)

If easier done outside of R (maybe in Excel itself, is also fine), but once its Tidy data, I will be using R to manipulate.

Thanks in advance :-)

Laurence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this function

```
parse_records <- function(x, delim = "~") {
  delim <- x == delim
  id <- cumsum(delim)
  rows <- split(x[!delim], id[!delim])
  dr <- max(lengths(rows))
  out <- as.data.frame(t(vapply(rows, `[`, character(dr), seq_len(dr))))
  row.names(out) <- NULL
  out
}
```

Then you can just

```
> parse_records(x)
      V1   V2       V3   V4       V5   V6       V7   V8
1 123456 $200 Bidder A $300 Bidder B $320 Bidder C <NA>
2 987654  $12 Bidder X  $15 Bidder Y  $20     <NA> <NA>
3 135678 $123 Bidder E $234 Bidder F $393 Bidder G $222
```

The key assumption is that your data is a character vector like this

```
> x
 [1] "123456"   "$200"     "Bidder A" "$300"     "Bidder B" "$320"     "Bidder C" "~"        "987654"   "$12"      "Bidder X" "$15"      "Bidder Y"
[14] "$20"      "~"        "135678"   "$123"     "Bidder E" "$234"     "Bidder F" "$393"     "Bidder G" "$222"
```

Data

```
c("123456", "$200", "Bidder A", "$300", "Bidder B", "$320", "Bidder C", 
"~", "987654", "$12", "Bidder X", "$15", "Bidder Y", "$20", "~", 
"135678", "$123", "Bidder E", "$234", "Bidder F", "$393", "Bidder G", 
"$222")
```

Answer (score 1):

Read in the file into R, then:

In base R you could do:

```
read.csv(text=gsub(', ~,?', '\n', toString(df[[1]])), header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)

      V1     V2        V3     V4        V5     V6        V7
1 123456  $200   Bidder A  $300   Bidder B  $320   Bidder C
2 987654   $12   Bidder X   $15   Bidder Y   $20
```

If you want the results in numeric format:

```
read.csv(text=gsub(', ~,?', '\n', toString(sub('[$]','',df[[1]]))), header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
      V1  V2        V3  V4        V5  V6        V7
1 123456 200  Bidder A 300  Bidder B 320  Bidder C
2 987654  12  Bidder X  15  Bidder Y  20
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  #Create a group column for every '~' in the data
  mutate(grp = cumsum(V1 == '~'), 
  #Extract the id value
         id = replace(V1, !grepl('^\\d+$', V1), NA)) %>%
  #Fill the id value to all the values in the group
  fill(id) %>%
  #Remove '~' and first id row from the data
  filter(V1 != '~' & !grepl('^\\d+$', V1)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  #For each group create column names
  mutate(col = paste0(c('value', 'bid'), rep(1:ceiling(n()/2), each = 2))) %>%
  #Get data in wide format
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = V1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)

#    id   value1 bid1     value2 bid2    value3   bid3    
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   
#1 123456 $200   Bidder A $300   Bidder B $320   Bidder C
#2 987654 $12    Bidder X $15    Bidder Y $20    Bidder Z
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("123456", "$200", "Bidder A", "$300", "Bidder B", 
"$320", "Bidder C", "~", "987654", "$12", "Bidder X", "$15", 
"Bidder Y", "$20", "Bidder Z", "~")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not your expected output, but this long output format is more clean:

```
# example data
x <- readLines(textConnection("123456
$200
Bidder A
$300
Bidder B
$320
Bidder C
~
987654
$12
Bidder X
$15
Bidder Y
$20
Bidder Z"))

do.call(rbind, c(make.row.names = FALSE,
                 lapply(split(x, cumsum(grepl("~", x))), function(i){
                   d <- i[ i != "~"]
                   res <- data.frame(id = d[1],
                                     Bidder = d[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)],
                                     Bid = d[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE)])
                   res$Bid <- as.numeric(gsub("$", "", res$Bid, fixed = TRUE))
                   res
                 }))
        )

#       id   Bidder Bid
# 1 123456 Bidder A 200
# 2 123456 Bidder B 300
# 3 123456 Bidder C 320
# 4 987654 Bidder X  12
# 5 987654 Bidder Y  15
# 6 987654 Bidder Z  20
```

Comment: @Laurence Upvote and/or accept as answer, "Thank you" comments get deleted.